# Deactiavte event seems to consume mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I have nonmodal form that I display using

```
myform.Show()
```

I close the form whenever the user clicks somewhere outside of the form. I do this successfully by handling the Deactivate event on the form. Done as so:

```
private void myform_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Close();
}
```

I have a custom calendar underneath this form.  I want to be able for the user to click on another day in calendar and the popup form go away automatically. Currently when the Deactivate event is called, the mouse click seems to be consumed. That is, the underlying calendar control does not receive the mouse click. Now the user has to click once to deactivate (close) the form and then another select a day. I'd like to do this all in one click.

I was hoping to be able to do something like

```
e.handled = false
```

in my Deactiavte handler but this of course is not an option. Help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The Mouse event is part of myForm not the other form where you calender in, if you need this event to trigger on the other form prior to this.close() you would call a method on your calender form forcing a mouse click event

Comment: But if i simplyl do not handle the Deactivate event in my form, the calendar belows gets the click (of course the window stays open now). The form is not a modal form so if I click somewhere else, it seems to be the mouse event should not be part of the form.